# How would a sapient species with two tongues organize their language?

Tags: xenobiology, aliens, language

I created a species of catlike aliens called Raachtunami (singular Raachtun) or Tutoans. They have extremely perceptive ears, a syrinx, and two tongues. This allows them to use several human phonetics at once, such as the sounds of the letters “b”, “l”, and “k” at once. The two tongues also let them speak with articulation while eating. But how would this ability influence the linguistic development of their speech?

Comment: I think there must be some misunderstanding. No, we do not have at present a general grand framework linking the "linguistic development of speech" (whatever it may be that you mean by this phrase) with the anatomy of the phonatory apparatus. (And we do not even know if is more than loosely linked to the anatomy of the phonatory apparatus.) Moreover, it is completely unclear what you mean by "an organ that functions between a larynx and a syrinx", given that the two are profoundly different.

Comment: I changed it, I did not mean to add the larynx thing.

Comment: I apologize, but this is not answerable on this Stack. We could, perhaps, give you insight into what sounds such a creature would be capable of making, but language is 100% an opinion-based aesthetic. It's estimated that humanity has developed [31,000 languages](https://www.uh.edu/engines/epi2723.htm) throughout history that have included, and excluded, every conceivable sound we can make. And that deep variety is why we don't answer questions about language development.

Comment: Kind of agree with the close for set reasons.. but this is not focused either and it lacks so many details ! It would also be an impossible question if you ask "opinions".. Any "opinion" on the subject would be false. I'll put my frame challenge here, instead of answering: mouth physiology and muscle configuration has many connections with the phonetics of a language, but you can't do the analysis of language bottom-up. It is impossible to tell what "language organization" would look like, based on anatomy only.

Comment: I'd suggest to work this out for yourself and tailor it to your story. Try think in terms of  sound characteristics only, not language.. focus on the phonetics first. And you'd have to agree geometric details, like the size and shape of the head and mouth, the shape of the larynx, make yourself a proper drawing of the mouth. Then, the basics: what would be the frequency range of pitch in this animal ? How are the tongues placed, how would muscles modify the shape of the mouth ? What cavities would be introduced by the two tongues and what are the dimensions of these.. Good luck, Jobah..

Answer (score 2):

### Not very different

[image]

There are humans with split tongues: usually the result of intentional body modification or a piercing gone wrong.  While they can learn to move the tongue halves independently, there is not a considerable difference in the sounds they can make vs an unmodified person.  At most it will give them a distinctive, but not magically unlock a whole new set of sounds.

Taking “b”, “l”, and “k” for example:

"K" is a sound made at the back of your mouth while width drawing your tongue and pressing a pop  of air through the back of your throat, "L" is made by pressing your tongue to the front of your mouth and vibrating your larynx, and "B" is made by filling your mouth with air and then separating your lips. You can already make the K+L sound simultaneously as in "**cl**ock" and the B+L sound as in "**bl**ock".  The harder sound here to do is K+B because you only have one air passage so you can't force a pop of air out the back of your mouth and between your lips at the same time.  So this is a sound that an extra tongue will not help you make.

If you want to make an alien race that can make significantly more complex sounds, it is better to modify the larynx than the tongue. Many birds for example can make way more sounds than humans without involving thier tongues at all because the can vibrate thier larynx with much more control giving them speaker like control to make mimic any sort of perceivable noise.

Comment: I see you have imagined the tongues side-by-side. I imagined the tongues one on top of the other.

Answer (score 0):

**Funny Talky Kittycats**

Their language would sound different to our languages. They have more movable parts in their mouth than a human. That means, all else being the same, they can make a wider range of phonemes than human beings. In fact they can make phonemes we have no way to write down or reproduce. This makes the language very hard to describe what it sounds like.

Sample transcription

> Calico Milkdrinker IV threw his head back and muttered, "ŦﻮŦ๔ﻮг  3гค๔  ค๒ гคкรՇ Ŧɭคкย๓ร5๓ค", as he descended from his wildebeast mount.

More samples available on request.